# Identifying collection subsets with RESTful URLs

Tags: rest

Suppose I want to get a list of all stores owned by my company in Maine. Conceptually, this request can be viewed as

```
/stores?state=Maine (All stores such that the state of the store is Maine)
```

or

```
/states/Maine/stores (All of Maine's stores)
```

Which is more RESTful, and why? Both seem to have their pluses and minuses from my understanding.

EDIT:

My original example has the problem that having stores as a subresource of states might not make intuitive sense, so here's another more detailed example: Suppose I can identify books globally by ISBN, or per-author by title (assuming no author names two of their own books alike). So, under this scheme `/books/0-525-94892-9` and `/authors/Ayn_Rand/books/Atlas Shrugged` would refer to the same book. So if I wanted all books by Ayn Rand, would I `GET /books?author=Ayn_Rand` or `GET /authors/Ayn_Rand/books`?

Comment: Considering states' names are unique :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is more RESTful, and why?

Both are equally RESTful (although, technically, REST URIs are opaque so it doesn't matter). Which is most apropriate for your use case depends on your resource heirarchy.

From your books example, I would use the ISBN as it is the cannonical identifier for that book as used elsewhere. There may be other books called "Atlas Shrugged" and there may be other authors called "Ayn Rand", or derivative editions of the same work might change the name, or list a second Author, if sufficiently edited. You need to provide at least two data, `{author-name, book-name}` and perhaps even `{publication-year}` to uniquely identify the book. With ISBN numbers, you only use one datum to identify the book.

A request for `/authors/{author-name}/books/{book-name}` might return either a `302 Found` response or better, return the book with a `Content-Location` header of `/books/{isbn}` and use a `rel="canonnical self"` link in the response to point to the ISBN URI for the resource.

**Edit**
I'll provide an example from my own API:
We have `jobs`, `contacts` and `sites`. All are top-level resources. Sites represent a physical place with an address. Contacts usually represent a company, but sometimes are individuals or an organisation like a school. A site has an `owner` which is a contact. The owner is the name on the sign when you go to that address. Jobs are top-level resources. Jobs have a `client`, a `site` and a `site_owner`. The job's client is a contact (not all contacts are clients), the job's site_owner is the owner of the site at the time of the job, since the owner of a site may change over time as premeses change hands and so on. We also sometimes do jobs for a client which is not the site owner (i.e. sub-contracter work). We need to keep a history of all works done on a site irrespective of who the client was, who owned the building at the time, etc.
Therefore, the job list for work done at a site for a specific client can be accessed under several URIs, `/contacts/{id}/sites/{id}/jobs`, `/sites/{id}/jobs?client={id}`, `/contacts/{id}/jobs?site={id}`, but really they are just filters on the list of jobs, and totally equivalent to `/jobs?client={id}&site={id}` and indeed all URIs are valid and eventually get to the same PHP file and set the same variables to the same values and run the same query, some just take a more circuitous route and do a few more `include` calls.
The **reason** why I allow all these different URIs is only because it allows my users to go "up" a level or two in their navigation heirarchy (variable "breadcrumbs" depending on the path taken to reach the list; which slightly alters the representation returned), and because the dataset is live, highly dynamic for things you are likely to be looking at, and so the HTML results are uncachable, so the tradeoff by not re-using a cannonical URI provides more benefits than down-sides.

The take-away from all that is:

- use a single unique identifier for your resources, or create one (`id`) if your resource does not inherently come with one (such as an ISBN)
- what URI you choose is irrelevent to how RESTful your API is

Answer (score 1):

Unless `/states` and `/states/Maine` are also resources in your system, I'd go with the first example.

Comment: Yeah, states was a bad example all things considered. I've updated the question to use a better one (authors and books), any suggestions on what to do if both Authors and Books are first-class resources?

Answer (score 1):

In both examples you give (states/stores and authors/books), I would use the latter scheme.

It allows you to expose the various different resources in an intuitive manner. The URI makes it clear which resources you expect, and it represents the constraints in use as a 'path' rather that a mess of `?key=value&foo=bar&so=on...`

Allow me to explain...

```
/authors/
```

Would return a list of all author resources.

```
/authors/Ayn_Rand/
```

Would return the Ayn Rand resource, which may contain information pertaining to Ms. Rand herself.

```
/authors/Ayn_Rand/books
```

Would return a list of books by Ayn Rand. This might look like a 'plain' list of books:

```
[
{
    title: 'Atlas Shrugged',
    genre: 'Fiction'
    slug: 'atlas_shrugged'
},
{
    title: 'The Fountainhead',
    genre: 'Fiction',
    slug: 'the_fountainhead'
},
{
    title: 'Capitalism: The Unknown Ideal',
    genre: 'Non-fiction',
    slug: 'capitalism_the_unknown_ideal'
}
]
```

You may wish to use also use Hypermedia to strictly refer to books by their ISBN:

```
...
{
    title: 'Atlas Shrugged',
    genre: 'Fiction',
    location: '/books/0-525-94892-9'
},
...
```